# Почему "передумала выходить ", а не "передумала выйти"?

Tags: глаголы

В предложении "Погода испортилась, и Анна передумала ВЫХОДИТЬ из дома"  почему "выходить", а не "выйти"? Согласно какому правилу здесь глагол в несовершенном виде? Например, в следующем предложении можно использовать оба вида. "Пошел ливень, и я не решился выйти из дома".

Answer (score 1):

Из словаря:

**ПЕРЕДУМАТЬ**, св. 1. Ещё раз подумав, изменить своё решение; перерешить, раздумать. Я передумал **идти** с тобой. Девушка передумала **выходить** замуж за этого человека. Он передумал **уезжать** из страны. Сын передумал поступать в университет.

Мы видим, что глагол передумать (изменить решение) сочетается с глаголами только **несовершенного вида.**

Смысл такой: Она решила выйти из дома, но потом решила не выходить (= передумала выходить).

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

1. **РЕШИТЬ**,  св. 1. что, с инф. или с придат. дополнит. После обдумывания прийти к какому-л. выводу, к необходимости каких-л. действий. **Р. учиться.** Р. посвятить себя искусству. Р. вопрос с отъездом. Внезапно р. уехать. **Р. изучать русский язык**.

Как мы видим, глагол "решить" сочетается с инфинитивом, имеющим форму как совершенного, так и несовершенного вида:  решил **изучить** язык; решил  **изучать** язык.

2. А теперь рассмотрим сочетание  «решить не делать что-либо»: **решил не изучать** язык.  При отрицании  глагол сочетается только с инфинитивом **несовершенного вида** (неверно: решить не изучить).
3. **А ПОЧЕМУ?**  Мы отрицаем **результативность действия**, но тот же отрицательный результат мы получим,  если  просто не будем изучать язык. Отсюда следует  **смысловая некорректность** сочетания «решил не изучить».
4. А теперь вернемся к глаголу «передумать». *Передумал выходить* – это *решил не выходить.*  А глагол «решить» **при отрицании** сочетается с инфинитивом **несовершенного вида**. Следовательно, глагола  «передумать»  также сочетается **с инфинитивом несовершенного вида.**

Конечно, в обыденной речи **грамматическую неточность** можно и не заметить: *передумал выйти* или *передумал выходить* – **какая разница!**
Но если уж кто-то "передумал выйти", то лучше начать с того, чтобы не выходить, результат от этого не изменится :)

Comment: Так это понятно, а вопрос в том, **почему** сочетается только с глаголами несовершенного вида.

Comment: Пример: *Он решил не выйти на работу.*

Comment: Вы видели, сколько значений у слова выйти? https://znachenie-slova.ru/выйти  Я разбирала "покинуть пределы".  А здесь вообще фразеология. Некоторые выходят на работу, чтобы показаться, а не работать.

Comment: Можно сделать вывод, что при нежелании делать что-то традиция использовать несовершенную форму, а исключения встречаются очень редко. Да, порой необходимо просто отсидеть на работе, если работы нет.

Comment: Ну тогда "не передумал..." = "решил выйти", а "выйти" опять же не подходит в первом случае. В вашей теории не всё сходится.

Answer (score 1):

Если сочтете за правило, то глагол ***"передумать"*** в роли первой части составного глагольного сказуемого требует при себе несовершенного вида инфинитива.

Вопрос только в том, с чем связано это свойство глагола *"передумать"*.
Аналогичным свойством обладают так называемые "фазовые" глаголы, означающие фазу действия смыслового глагола. *"Передумать"* тоже можно отнести (с небольшой оговоркой) к фазовым. Сравните: ***начал писать, закончил редактировать, перестал спрашивать***. Значение *"передумать"* функционально близко к  *"перестать", "прекратить"* - с той лишь разницей, что может семантически означать "фазу" даже еще не начатого действия. Ну а дальше все очевидно.

> Известное свойство фазовых глаголов - таких как *начать, продолжать,*
> *перестать* - состоит в том, что подчиненный им глагол в инфинитиве
> может быть только несов. вида.

И.Е. Падучева

Цитирую по http://rlls.hlju.edu.cn/eyu_ru/content_view.asp?id=842, к сожалению не имею возможности сейчас искать другой источник.